# Displaying multiple data in checkbox from database when a button is clicked

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have a dropdown with a checkbox in it and those data are also stored in database. How will I display the checkbox I clicked if I hit the Go button?

[

```html
<div class="col-md-6" align="right">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-light" multiple="multiple" id="prelim" title="PRELIM">
                <option id="1" class="opt" value="GENERAL">GENERAL</option>
                <option id="2" class="opt" value="LOCATION/SITE PLAN">LOCATION/SITE PLAN</option>
                <option id="3" class="opt" value="SEDIMENT/CONTROL PLAN">SEDIMENT/CONTROL PLAN</option>
                <option id="4" class="opt" value="FOUNDATION PLAN">FOUNDATION PLAN</option>
                <option id="5" class="opt" value="TIMBER FLOOR">TIMBER FLOOR</option>
                <option id="6" class="opt" value="GROUND FLOOR PLAN">GROUND FLOOR PLAN</option>
                <option id="7" class="opt" value="FIRST FLOOR PLAN">FIRST FLOOR PLAN</option>
                <option id="8" class="opt" value="FIRST FLOOR FRAMING PLAN">FIRST FLOOR FRAMING PLAN</option>
                <option id="9" class="opt" value="DRAINAGE PLAN">DRAINAGE PLAN</option>
                <option id="10" class="opt" value="BRACING PLAN">BRACING PLAN</option>
                <option id="11" class="opt" value="ROOF PLAN">ROOF PLAN</option>
                <option id="12" class="opt" value="ROOF FRAMING PLAN">ROOF FRAMING PLAN</option>
                <option id="13" class="opt" value="ELECTRICAL PLAN">ELECTRICAL PLAN</option>
                <option id="14" class="opt" value="ELEVATIONS">ELEVATIONS</option>
                <option id="15" class="opt" value="CROSS SECTIONS">CROSS SECTIONS</option>
                <option id="16" class="opt" value="HILL ZONE SPECIFIC CHECKS">HILL ZONE SPECIFIC CHECKS</option>
                <option id="17" class="opt" value="FRAMING">FRAMING</option>
                <option id="18" class="opt" value="DETAILS(FOUNDATION">DETAILS(FOUNDATION)</option>
                <option id="19" class="opt" value="DETAILS(ROOF)">DETAILS(ROOF)</option>
                <option id="20" class="opt" value="DETAILS(WINDOWS&DOOR)">DETAILS(WINDOWS&DOOR)</option>
                <option id="21" class="opt" value="DETAILS(SPECIFIC)">DETAILS(SPECIFIC)</option>
                <option id="22" class="opt" value="ENERGY EFFICIENCY">ENERGY EFFICIENCY</option>
                <option id="23" class="opt" value="SPECIFICATION">SPECIFICATION</option>
            </select>
            
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="go" data-target="#confirm" data-toggle="modal" value="GO">
</div
```

]

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to need to provide more information than that. So - examples of your code, is the data currently stored in the database, what does your code currently look like? Thanks.

Comment: I already added a snippet.